# How to set ANDROID_HOME path in ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu

How to set ANDROID_HOME path in ubuntu?

Please provide the steps.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: The question was not related on setting a specific environment variable in Ubuntu; this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368367/509565 is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 355):

In the console just type these :

```sh
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

If you want to make it permanent just add those lines in the ~/.bashrc file

Comment: where can i find ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @mVJ simply do `vim ~/.bashrc` in your terminal. The folder you are in has no importance

Comment: @Dario Quintana what mans by current location, which location can you explain about this

Comment: @Dinesh I think he refers to change the Android SDK location if it is different, for example, if you have chosen another directory when installing it.

Comment: I think the PATH should now be `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`, see below. In the SDK 29.0.3 I just installed, there is no `tools` directory anymore.

Comment: By using terminal , Run below command , you will be able to edit  the file "sudo gedit ~/.bashrc"
after that paste above command

Comment: It is worth noting to know your default terminal, if it is zsh as in my case add the stated lines to the bottom of the file by `sudo nano ~/,zshrc`. Remember to save the file. That should work.

Answer (score 146):

I would like to share an answer that also demonstrates approach using the Android SDK provided by the Ubuntu repository:

**Install Android SDK**

```
sudo apt-get install android-sdk
```

**Export environmental variables**

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
```

Comment: That's the right answer when installing `android-sdk` package from apt. Thanks!

Comment: Correct answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: As of 2020, Ubuntu terminal returns this error ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)

Comment: Correct answer for me. Thanks Mate!!

Answer (score 131):

Assuming you have the sdk extracted at `~/Android/Sdk`,

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

1. Add the above lines to the file **`~/.bashrc`** (located at `home/username/.bashrc`) to make it permanent for the current user. Run  `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes or restart your terminal.

   *(**or**)*
2. Run the above lines on a terminal window to make it available for the session.

**To test if you have set it up correctly,**

Run the below commands on a terminal window

1. **`echo $ANDROID_HOME`**

   ```
   user@host:~$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
   /home/<user>/Android/Sdk
   ```
2. **`which android`**

   ```
   user@host:~$ which android
   /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools/android
   ```
3. Run `android` on a terminal window, If it opens up **Android SDK Manager**, you are good to go.

Comment: Note that you have to restart the terminal before those `echo` commands will work. I usually run `exec $SHELL`.

Comment: For the third point I get this message: "The "android" command is deprecated."

Comment: @Mate / all - It says: _"The "android" command is deprecated. (...) For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager ..."_ : therefore add (per above): `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin` then source `~/.profile` (or .bashrc) if you don't want to logout.. then try running 'sdkmanager --licenses'. Then try compiling.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, this one solved my adb path issue.

Answer (score 49):

better way is to reuse  ANDROID_HOME variable in path variable. if your ANDROID_HOME variable changes you just have to make change at one place.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/arshid/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit more, please ? Try to detail what you are doing and why it is a "better way". Thank you !

Comment: @Ninetainedo I think its better because he "reused" ANDROID_HOME variable in PATH.

Comment: note the `arshid` part needs to be replaced with the current user's name

Answer (score 41):

Initially go to your home and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> it will show you hidden files now look for `.bashrc` file, open it with any text editor then place below lines at the end of file.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/varun/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/varun/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/varun/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Please change `/home/varun/Android/Sdk` path to your SDK path.
Do the same for tools and platform-tools.

After this save `.bashrc` file and close it.

Now you are ready to use ADB commands on terminal.

Answer (score 34):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file. Log-out and log-in. I have my sdk in `$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk` you have to replace it with where you keep your sdk folder

```
# Android Path
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk:$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH

# For SDK version r_08 and higher, also add this for adb:
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH
```

Comment: I think running `source ~/.bashrc` can substitute for logging out then logging in.

Comment: @JVE999 yes for that particular terminal session.

Comment: You could do `export PATH=$PATH(...)` in one like. Works both ways :)

Answer (score 34):

first open the .bashrc file by gedit ~/.bashrc

> `# Added ANDROID_HOME variable.
>   export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
>   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
>   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

save the file and reopen the terminal

> `echo $ANDROID_HOME`

it will show the path like `/home/pathTo/Android/Sdk`

Comment: this should be the verified answer! thank you so much

Answer (score 16):

Applies to Ubuntu and Linux Mint

In the archive:

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

Add to the end:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
```

Restart the terminal and doing: echo $ HOME or $ PATH, you can know these variables.

Comment: thanks for your answer this is permanent solution

Answer (score 11):

Download the Android SDK to the machine. (Suppose that the location is /home/zelong/Android/Sdk) (home/username/Android/Sdk)

Add these lines to the file ~/.bashrc (located at home/username/.bashrc)

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/zelong/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

This will make it permanent for the current user because every time the machine boots, it will run this script and set the enviroment path.

After making this change, remember to save it.

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes or restart your terminal.

**Test if it works:**

```
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/zelong/Android/Sdk
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~$ which android
/home/zelong/Android/Sdk/tools/android
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~$ which adb
/home/zelong/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

As we can see,

`android` command line locates under `tools`

`adb` command line locates under `platform-tools`

Answer (score 7):

This is what work for me,
Assuming you have the sdk extracted at `~/Android/Sdk`,

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Add the above lines to the file `~/.bashrc` (located at `home/username/.bashrc`) to make it permanent for the current user. Run source `~/.bashrc` to apply the changes or restart your terminal.
(or)
Run the above lines on a terminal window to make it available for the session.
To test if you have set it up correctly,
Run the below commands on a terminal window

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME

user#host:~$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

You will get

```
/home/<user>/Android/Sdk
```

You can run this too

```
which android

user#host:~$ which android

/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools/android
```

Run android on a terminal, If it opens up Android SDK Manager, you are good to go.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it works with a little change. Simply by putting :$PATH at the end.

```
# andorid paths
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 4):

you can edit the environment variable file in Ubuntu to set android home globally.

[1] run this command in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

[2] your envirmnent file content will look like the below one

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

[3] in environment file add android sdk path as follows:-

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
ANDROID_HOME="/home/yourPathTo/Android/Sdk"
```

[4] then you can check the Android home path in the terminal with the following command:-

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

**If path is still not set then restart the system to get the applied changes.**

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal just type these 3 commands to set the ANDROID_HOME Variable :

```
$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
```

`/Android/Sdk` is the location of Sdk, this might get change in your case

```
$ PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
$ PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools `
```

**Note :** This will set the path temporarily so what ever action
you have to perform, perform on the same terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you run android with sudo it will install sdk in /root/Android/Sdk
so check if that is the case.
And if you are using dont run cordova with sudo it will look sdk in root also may be. 
Above code for setting path is works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem with linux ANDROID_HOME path

> Note:
> 1- Add parameters
>
> 2- Make or Rebuild project
>
> 3- Restart your PC

How to add parameters using terminal:

Open your terminal write

> gedit .bashrc

another window will be open and then add the following lines at the end of the windows.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

then back to terminal and type

> source .bashrc

to save your changes in bashrc file at the end restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

add to file

```
~/.profile 


export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
```

Path to the SDK

Then reset the computer

Comment: I was struggling for the last 3 days and I was able to solve it by just adding a path in .profile. I am using ubuntu V20.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue,
in the terminal you can type:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
```

or any other location depending on where you installed the sdk.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su -
gedit ~/.bashrc
export PATH=${PATH}:/your path
export PATH=${PATH}:/your path
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Comment: Add some explanations to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can append this line at the end of .bashrc file-

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/opt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/"
```

here /opt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ is installation directory of Sdk. 
.bashrc file is located in home folder

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

or if you have sublime installed

```
subl ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

open ~/.bashrc file and paste at the end

```
export PATH=$PATH{}:/path-from-home-dir/android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH{}:/path-from-home-dir/android/sdk/platform-tools
```