# set android home in ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

i downloaded the sdk from android official website and installed the latest build tools using android sdk manager. I set android home as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308422/android-sdk-and-path)

but when i run `cordova build android` i got `ANDROID_HOME is not your path`.

Then i did as same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps) but no luck.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is your path to android sdk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please verify that the SDK you downloaded really is located at the location you set. Do this by:

```
echo $PATH
```

and

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

and verify that the last part of PATH and ANDROID_HOME is identical with where you unzipped the Downloaded zip.

If referring to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308422/android-sdk-and-path) than you would have to replace "/opt/android/sdk" with the folder where you unzipped the SDK.

If using sudo you need to either call sudo with `sudo -E` flag or add the ANDROID_HOME to the `Defaults env_keep` in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Hi Ben , this was my `echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/saravanan/software/android-sdk-linux
` android home and path was `echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/saravanan/software/android-sdk-linux:/home/saravanan/software/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/saravanan/software/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
`  but no luck

Comment: Are there any aliases that so that cordova get's startet as an other user? Or are you using sudo?

You could try to directly give the path while starting cordova like `ANDROID_HOME=/home/saravanan/software/android-sdk-linux cordova build android`

Comment: Yes Ben , I am used sudo every time i tried to build a project. Your solution is working but is any other way to avoid giving ADNDROID_HOME at cordova build

Comment: I added it to the comment