# Ionic Error: may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Tags: android, compiler-errors, ionic-framework

I'm running Ionic on Ubuntu. I have the Android sdk installed and already installed the tools to work with it.

When I try to run `ionic build android` I got the error:

```
Running command: /home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I'm tried to look this on google, and have too much information and no solution about this.

Someone already got this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find my answer at this post :

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have met this error before.
But as your log we can see what the problem is:

> Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.

You have installed the `sdk` but haven't set the `PATH` to it.

#### For Windows user try the following step:

- Open up the System Environment from:
- `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> Select `Advance` tab
- Click on `Environment Variables...`
- In the `User variables for ...` section click on the `New` button.
- Then type `ANDROID_HOME` in `Variable name`, and `the path` to the sdk folder in `Variable Value`
- `OK`, `OK`, `OK`
- Restart the command line and try again with `ionic` command.

#### For Ubuntu, I don't use this OS so please check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps)

Comment: "Control Panel" This is not for windows?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Did you check the Ubuntu solution?