# Is GUI for Android SDK manager gone?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I rarely do something for Android so I'm a bit confused. While back there were two type of installations - Android Studio and just Android SDK. I have IDEA so I don't need Studio. Typically I download SDK that have UI tool to download its components.

I just got https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip and I can't see UI SDK Manager in it. There is `bin/sdkmanager` shell script. But it's kinda inconvenient for my purpose because going through output of `--list`, copy-pasting packages names and running `sdkmanager` would take too much time.

What's the way of installing this quickly now ?

PS. I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 in case it matters.

PS2. I just tried `sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"` as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) but it gave no output after me agreeing to terms. Where did it install SDK files? Did it even install it? Amazing.

Comment: Try `Android > SDK Manager > Launch Standalone SDK Manager`.

Comment: It's not a real solution but what I can say is that on Windows I have a SDK Manager.exe in the root of the android-sdk directory. If that helps (probably not). In case you are right, did you try to download a less recent version?

Comment: @Enzokie I guess it's something in Android Studio ? I have standard IDEA with Android plugin thus there is no such menu option. Or at least I don't see it :)

Comment: With android sdk v26 the GUI is completely gone. It is only accessible from android studio. Too bad Google aggressively promoting android studio.

Comment: Alternative SDK manager is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244605/971547

Comment: @Bharat@Beppi [The SDK GUI is here to stay!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)

Comment: The GUI was deprecated and removed starting with SDK tools v25. To get the GUI, install v24 and update it [as explained here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Looks like [I'm not the only one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230705) who had to deal with this idiocy. The way to install it

1. Unpack [zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip) to some `/parent` folder so it has `/parent/tools`. I extracted content of zip's `tools` to `/androidsdk` and it was mistake. Script couldn't find it.
2. Set `ANDROID_HOME` to `/parent` folder.
3. Run `/parent/tools/android sdk` to see SDK Manager's GUI.

Google, was it hard to leave script that does the above in installation zip so people don't need to waste 40 minutes googling around ?

Comment: mmm looks strange to me... the env variable `ANDROID_HOME` is never used inside the `tools/android` script...

Comment: @Lino I just realize that it was used by the IDE, therefore it might not be necessary in the OP's problem :(

Comment: Ridiculous this isn't documented somewhere. I had to redownload the SDK and all the old tools where gone, just had a bunch of seemingly random batch files.

Comment: Didn't understand this solution. Is the sdkmanager.exe gone or is just a "bug" in the installation?

Comment: What "zip" are you talking about?

Comment: Now, `android sdk` prints out `Invalid or unsupported command "sdk"`

Comment: `The "android" command is deprecated. For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.`

Comment: What the frick. I don't care about or need Android Studio. This is ridiculous.

Comment: I think this answer is obsolete now. it doesn't work with current sdk

Comment: Since android decided to do this, my Cordova project can't me installed & working on other devices so i have to work on my 10 year old laptop....
Some plugins I use are deprecated in cordova 7.0 but never re-created..

Comment: I agree. Google cant even make their Angular.io example project work properly. It baffles me how a company this big makes these kind of mistakes

Comment: I understand the feeling about having to install Android Studio when not needed, but on the other side Google has now made it completely portable, so at least it won't be entangled with your system. Look for the zip / no installer on the google / android website.

Comment: @agpt There is a newer alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330

Answer (score 58):

Officially GUI is gone, but pleasant people saved the last of it for us:
[installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe](https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe)

According for this [announcment](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) Google doesn't intend to support ADT pluging for Eclipse since June 2015, and so as GUI for ADT at all. They explain the decision with an entire switching to Android Studio. There are no links on official Android sources where to download last GUI version, because they find it as having potential security bugs.

So you have chance to download the last saved version, till the link will not be changed. If it already happened try [to search by tag](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe&oq=installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.344j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Thank to [Losin' Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309883/losin-me) for links:

- Windows (No installer): [dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip)
- Mac OS X: [dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip)
- Linux: [dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz)

Found on [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160602115203/https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Comment: +1.Managed to successfully launch an emulator with Android Monitor to view the logcat without the need for Android Studio with this answer. Thank you. Prefer my GUIs then command lines. Ergh.

Comment: Windows (No installer): https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip

Comment: Found on: https://web.archive.org/web/20160602115203/https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: The eclipse Andmore project is working on bring these tools back to life.  So hopefully you'll have access. It was short sited of Google to force you to go through the Android Studio UI only for these options.   Keep an eye out on the Andmore project for when we will have this available.  I'll try to update this comment as well when it is available.

Comment: Thanks for GUI Windows Installer

Comment: @Unknownweirdo  Please see my post showing how to [use the GUI in latest SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)

Comment: This may be a few years past the fact, but there is a changeset available in which at least some of the original SDK tools support was removed - https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/sdk/+/331978 

It should be possible to fork the AOSP platform/sdk source code, starting at either the changeset before that one, or starting at that before the later one in which it was git-cherry-picked at the AOSP platform/sdk source repository. I'm not sure how well it may integrate with existing AOSP designs, but as a matter of the tooling, hopefully it'll be trivial.

Answer (score 26):

Late to the party, but you can download v24.4 installer like the good old day [here](http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/download/dd03cc329af0cd74b0e34afce1b4888e/). It will update itself to v25.x and everything works as expected. Also a big ef'u Google.

Update 2021-07 : This tool does not offer build tools version >= 30 and won't show newer packages anymore

Comment: Note the OP was using Ubuntu and this is a Windows link - but it was what I needed so I upvoted.

Comment: I have version 25.5 :)

Comment: @andreszs If you want you can still use the latest version i.e `27.3.8` [with GUI support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)

Answer (score 11):

Since Android released build tools 25.3.0, they removed `android` CLI command and replaced it with `avdmanager` and `sdkmanager` located inside your `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/tools`

Run this command to get a list of available packages in *sdk-style path*:
`sdkmanager --list`

Run this command to install a specific image: `sdkmanager --verbose "system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86"`

Comment: To put it simple, your answer is "Yes, GUI is gone?". This is terrible to install all this stuff via CLI...

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: @RAM237 I am proud to say the GUI is here to stay see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330

Answer (score 8):

From the command line, just type

```
tools/android sdk
```

and the usual GUI for the Android SDK will be prompted.

Hope this helps

Comment: @expert this looks like the answer you need. I tried it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Enzokie Looks like something is still missing. I see jar in question in `lib` folder but I'm hesitant to read bash 3.5Kb script to find out where Google made mistake.

Comment: @expert maybe you need to set the environment variable. The `./android sdk` is working in my case assuming the I `cd` to the correct folder.

Comment: @Enzokie Which environment variable ? Where in documentation can I read that ?

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one who had problems with this idiocy https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230705

Comment: @expert [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28889144/5217712) In this case you need to have a text editor like vim or gedit to open it. Ex. `gedit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me a lot!

Comment: This no longer works either. "Invalid or unsupported command "sdk" and "The 'android' command is deprecated. For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio. Thans Obama.

Comment: @Nilzor See if this post addresses your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330

Answer (score 5):

If You have Android Studio, you can point your sdk manager in Android Studio to where you just installed your SDK. You can manage it from there. That's what I had to do. The command line was so tough for me as I didn't get the full package names when running **`sdkmanager --list`** command

Comment: This saved me, instructions all over the web are outdated, and expect you to be able to open the gui from the command line. This was the easiest solution by far-

Comment: that sucks. I liked the stand alone GUI.

Comment: Google just decided to follow Apple's policy: don't let the developers relax and focus on development, we need to do something so that they spend most of their time configuring our stuff }:-[

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the link for download android sdk](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com.br/p/android-sdk-tools.html) with GUI for windows, linux and mac:

Uncompressing and put the folder named tools inside androidsdk directory, search for android.bat: it's open GUI in windows.

Download packages and develop apps.

Answer (score 2):

For using with Xamarin, The official [`Xamarin SDK Manager`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager) is now available for Visual Studio 2017 and above. It can be installed from under "Cross Platform Mobile" workload in the Visual Studio Installer. It replaces Google's standalone SDK Manager (which was deprecated in version 25.2.3 of the Android SDK Tools package).

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for bumping a necropost. But I have just released a simple Android SDK GUI. Maybe this little weekend project could save some people from headache of using sdkmanager command line or downloading android-tools twice.

You could check my project at [**AndroidGUI**](https://github.com/devilxnux/AndroidGUI/releases).

Fork as you please or better yet send me PR. Any help would be very much appreciated.

PS: It would be very useful if somebody could point me to the latest sdklib-*.jar source code. So that I could interface with Android SDK directly.

Answer (score 1):

In the tools directory search for ' android.bat ' file and run it , GUI for SDK manager will open .

Comment: I've tried this and no GUI opens.  I get a message saying the "android" command is deprecated and to use the tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and avdmanager.bat files which do not give you a GUI.

Comment: I guess they're trying to force people to download the Android Studio IDE, because I think that's my only solution, I don't have time to deal with the commandline for selecting and installing android images.  Something that used to be easy was just made 10 times more difficult and annoying.

Comment: That how it worked last week. Not any more. Not having a stand alone GUI sucks.

Comment: It's a very cheap trick to force users install Android Studio when it's completely unneeded.

Comment: They asked for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For all Windows users: I just made a "porting" of the old GUI executables...

although porting is a big word, I just changed the executable so it would read andoid_gui.bat instead of android.bat, and added that file and some required libs (although I think only archquery.jar is needed, I also put sdkmanager.jar, sdkstats.jar and sdkuilib.jar; it seems to work even without them so let me know if they are not needed)

Just extract it in the SDK directory

[Download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zhdwipkX7sCAn9h8lHYE33ILgYemal3U/view?usp=sharing)