# sdk manager doesn't open in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, xamarin.forms

I needed to move my sdk folder because the path didn't use to allow it run
Then it is in C:
But the sdk manager doesnt open in xamarin anymore
nether in the windows menu...
Do I need move it again?
How can I solve that?

Comment: First confirm VS is pointing to the right path of the Android SDK.

Comment: Yeah, it is pointing to the right path.

Comment: Try going to the path and find a program called "SDK Manager.exe" double click on this and see what happens. Also do not forget the simplest of the solutions: restarting your computer (this helps many times).

Comment: cmd open and after close...only it

Answer (score 1):

> ***Google removed the GUI for SDK starting from version 26***. If you're using version 26, try downgrading to version 25. Remember that you can still open the SDK from **Android Studio**.

Source: [Is GUI for Android SDK manager gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407396/is-gui-for-android-sdk-manager-gone)

### Alternative

You can use an open source GUI interface based on sdkmanager.bat: [B4A Sdk Manager](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/gui-sdk-manager-for-newer-versions-of-android-tools.80090)

[image: B4A SDK Manager]

[image: B4A AVD Manager]

> It can be useful for any developer **who doesn't use Android Studio.**

Comment: Then MS should provide his own GUI