# Cannot select Cordova Global on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I have a cordova app on visual studio 2017. VS2017 uses Cordova 6.3.1 however I need to use Cordova version 7.1.0.

So I had to install cordova globally as specified in this link https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html

Then I opened config.xml from my project and went to change Toolset Name, but it shows "Global Cordova Version (not currently installed)"

Any help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), you can install **Cordova 7.1.0** by typing this in a command line interface window (`cmd.exe`):

> npm install -g cordova@7.1.0

Now, because **changing the CLI version is not as reliable as we would want**, I suggest to follow these steps to create your new app in Visual Studio 2017:

Go to `File > New > Project > Blank App (Apache Cordova)`

Open `config.xml` in View Code mode and find this:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
```

Replace with:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>7.1.0</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
```

Where `7.1.0` is your globally installed Cordova version.

Select `Device` as target.

Now `Build > Build Solution`

Save, close and reload the project. When you access `config.xml` in designer mode you'll see **Global Cordova 7.1.0** as the selected toolset.

[image]

In order to build you may need to use the external Android SDK Build Tools (**API 26**) instead of the ones provided by Visual Studio (API 25).

[image]

Use the [Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407396/is-gui-for-android-sdk-manager-gone) to manage versions, no need to get Android Studio for this.

[image]

Remember to follow [the **guidelines** from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/change-cordova-version/change-cli-version?view=toolsforcordova-2015) when changing the CLI on existing projects. However I strongly recommend **creating a new one and then importing your files and adding your plugins** to avoid potential problems.