# Ubuntu:launch android SDK manager GUI using command line

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools

I have installed android-SDK without using the android studio, but I can't find proper command to launch SDK manager GUI

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

But it didn't say anything about GUI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407663/7505436

Answer (score 0):

The android-SDK no have GUI any more... I sugest install Android Studio or another emulator...