# Update Tools For Apache Cordova in Visual Studio

Tags: apache, visual-studio, cordova, apache-cordova, tools-for-apache-cordova

I am new to apache cordova and i'm trying to build a client app for my asp.net mvc website, using apache cordova in visual studio. 
but visual studio 2017 tools for apache cordova installs cordova 6.3.1 and some plugins like onesignal can't work on it.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

That is a known issue but it can be fixed following these steps:

Assuming you have already installed **Cordova 7.1.0** gobally using `npm install -g cordova@7.1.0`

In **Visual Studio 2017** go to `File > New > Project > Blank App (Apache Cordova)`

Open `config.xml` in View Code mode and find this:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
```

Replace with:

```
<vs:toolsetVersion>7.1.0</vs:toolsetVersion>
<engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
```

Where `7.1.0` is your global Cordova version.

Note how `cordova-android` has been increased to `6.3.0` as well.

Feel free to try using [cordova-android 6.4.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/11/09/android-release.html) or [cordova-android 7.0.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html), however they may or may not introduce some issues (with Gradle for example). I have tested `6.3.0` but certain plugins may require a newer version.

Select `Device` as target.

Now `Build > Build Solution`

Save, close and reload the project. When you access `config.xml` in designer mode you'll see **Global Cordova 7.1.0** as the selected toolset.

[image]

In order to build you may need to use the external Android SDK Build Tools (**API 26**) instead of the ones provided by Visual Studio (API 25).

[image]

Use the [Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407396/is-gui-for-android-sdk-manager-gone) to manage versions, no need to get Android Studio for this.

[image]

Remember to follow [the **guidelines** from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/change-cordova-version/change-cli-version?view=toolsforcordova-2015) when changing the CLI on existing projects. However I strongly recommend **creating a new one and then importing your files and adding your plugins** to avoid potential problems.

Comment: The <engine> spec version number don't seem to be preserved on Rebuild. You actually need to change those in the package.json file under dependencies. During a build they get written into the config.xml