# ANDROID_HOME is not set (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04

I have followed all steps mentioned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps)

I have set `ANDROID_HOME` and set PATH in `bashrc` file.

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sanjay/Android/Sdk
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/sanjay/Android/Sdk/tools
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/sanjay/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

But still the error `"environment variable is not set"`, `"It should be set to SDK home directory"` pops up every time I try to build an app.

Please help to resolve this issue..

Comment: Can you please add the more details means your bash file ?

Comment: you need to either logout-login or run `source .bashrc` for the updated file to take effect

Comment: I added the details. Do I need to provide more?

Comment: I did logout-login. Also did a reboot once. But still no effect. When I echo $ANDROID_HOME or $PATH, the changes are reflected

Comment: Are you create the hybrid mobile app or native android app ?

Comment: and please try to run android command on terminal

Comment: I am building a native android app

Comment: If you mean to run adb command on terminal, it works.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: Are you starting your IDE as root?

Comment: Yes, I am using Android studio. And I did not start IDE as root. I created a desktop entry for Android studio from Android studio->Tools. I start the IDE from desktop itself

Comment: is the SDK path set in android studio sdk manager?

Comment: Yes. The SDK path is set correctly in SDK manager

Comment: Assuming you are building the project using gradle. You should post the gradle output near the error message, as to specify what build step or tool causes the error.

Comment: The error I get is:

:IME:installPlatformSDK
Error : [installPlatformSDK] environment variable ANDROID_HOME is not set. It should be set to SDK home directory

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':IME:installPlatformSDK'.
> Error : [installPlatformSDK] environment variable ANDROID_HOME is not set. It should be set to SDK home directory

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces betwen the path and `ANDROID_HOME` in this line:

```
export ANDROID_HOME = /home/sanjay/Android/Sdk
```

such that it reads:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sanjay/Android/Sdk
```

Comment: dont think that is the problem.. adb works in the terminal according to OP

Comment: I tried that, logged out and logged in. But the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

It is not that difficult but you got to make your project make know weatabouts of your SDK.

Try following in your terminal

temporary option: In terminal root of your project

export ANDROID_HOME=[sdk location]

gradle build

===================================

adding path permanent: 
Linux -  ~/.bashrrc

export ANDROID_HOME=[sdd location]

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH