# Where is the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in ubuntu server?

Tags: android, jenkins

I run a build on a ubuntu 16.04 server with no xorg or GUI of any kind, and I am trying to run a simulator on it. this is what I get on the console

```
$ /opt/android//tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5688,5689 -report-console tcp:5815,max=60 -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
Build was aborted
```

How do I set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in ubuntu?

Answer (score 8):

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk` in your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04, and for me the path is /root/Android/Sdk.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/root/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score -9):

Type in terminal,

```
echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

this command will display ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable path.

IF NOTHING APPEARS THEN SET IT WITH THIS

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = yourandroidsdkpath
```

For displaying follow first command.

You can refer in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps)

Comment: how do I know the android sdk path?

Comment: JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT are two different things. You should close this answer.