# InvocationTargetExceptionMessage is : It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation, appium-android

I am trying to set up a simple selenium Framework to run off Appium.  The test should simply open Chrome on an android device.  I have created my Baseclass which us unfortunately returning an error

My original thinking was that this issue was related to the URL which is http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub, I changed it but the error was still displayed.  I have also changed my Java version client but every time I do this another error appears!!

My Appium version is the following..

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.14.2
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

**this is my BaseClass**

```
package tests;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class BaseClass {


    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {

        try {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus 7");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "0911b4aa");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
   //       caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,caps);


        }catch(Exception  exp) {
            System.out.append("cause is  : "+exp.getCause());
            System.out.append("Message is : "+exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        System.out.print("I am running a test");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

**This is my POM File...**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>Android_F1_TV</groupId>
        <artifactId>Android_F1_TV</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

**The errors returned are.....**

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
cause is  : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionMessage is : It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'Taylers-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c63:8428:5e15:4731%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriverorg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'Taylers-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c63:8428:5e15:4731%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at tests.BaseClass.setup(BaseClass.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:584)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:185)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in ["/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin/aapt"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/usr/local/share/android-sdk'?
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'Taylers-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c63:8428:5e15:4731%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in ["/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin/aapt"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/usr/local/share/android-sdk'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:826:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:447:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    ... 40 more
I am running a testFAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest teardown
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tests.BaseClass.teardown(BaseClass.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:853)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

PASSED: sampleTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

    enter code here
```

I can see in the error response that AAPT is mentioned and that is to do with the Android SDK.  here is my .profile file where my SDK info is stored...

Adding path of platform tools folder in path environments variable
export PATH="/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796/platform-tools:$PATH"

Setting PATH for ANDROID_HOME
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be that it does not find the class `LoggingHandler`. That class is usually in the selenium-api dependency. You can try to use 2.53.1 version instead of 3.4.0. That version has the missing class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so now I have a new error, do I post it here or create a new one?

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x     AND THIS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu       may help you

Comment: That's the thing, I have done that and can't work out why it isn't working.