# Can't change flutter android-sdk path

Tags: android, linux, flutter

I'm setting up flutter in my laptop (Elementary OS), the case is I'm trying to be able develop flutter without Android Studio and using VSCode to make it lightweight, the step I did is installing flutter, download manually android-sdk, and move it to `usr/lib/Android`, install gradle, and openJDK8,

I did setting up Android Environtment, export `ANDROID_HOME` to `usr/lib/Android`, setting up with `sdkmanager` to download system-images, etc

I can run the flutter command on terminal, the problem is in the `android-sdk` path, I already changed the config with `flutter config --android-sdk /usr/lib/Android`, but, the `flutter doctor -v` command shows

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /usr/lib/android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
```

and the `flutter config` command shows

```
Settings:
  android-sdk: /usr/lib/Android/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you can try this.
   flutter config --android-sdk < path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
2. export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk"
   export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

HAPPY CODING :)

Comment: I already try (1) as I describe in the question, and tried (2) and still not working

Comment: try again (2) it will helpful to you and check your android sdk location then add that path in ANDROID_HOME .

Comment: follow the below link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu

Comment: thank you, it's work after try to following the link you provided, now I have another problem about gradle, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Android SDK** to path variable.

Add `...\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` to your path.