# Ubuntu Android Emulator not connecting with react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu and learning react native. I installed Android Studio and opened an emulator. I am getting this following error.

```
Error: spawn /opt/android-studio/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
```

When I check this path, its installed in

```
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

My PATH variables are,

> /home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/android-studio/bin:/opt/android-studio/bin

even though I update the path with

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools"
```

I am getting the same error again and again. How do I fix them permenantly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set ANDROID\_HOME path in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu)

Comment: My Android studio installed in ~/learning/android-studio. My bashrc file contents are,
```export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-studio
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin```

Comment: ```export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"```
I added the above and restarted bashrc with ```source ~/.bashrc```
But still i am getting same error.

Comment: You sure about the environment setup https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=linux and installed Android SDK, Android SDK Platform & Android Virtual Device?